# Getting access token for portal users through OAuth

Tags: customer-portal, oauth2, php

I need to get access token for portal users to access a site that was developed in salesforce .I should use OAuth2 method in php to get this access token.Can anyone help me out in solving this issue.

```
 `<?php

session_start();

$token_url = "https://xtremeforce-developer-edition.ap1.force.com/force/services/oauth2/token";

$params = "&grant_type=password"     .       "&client_id=3MVG9Y6d_Btp4xp44G2jyLqvoeOz.ufD8BZWwFyNOipRiuD2tpPqyJoRWwPeTMsX5JmAhCEUt0_E7TgxWo2eu"     
     . "&client_secret=xxxxx5808856995" 
 //."organizationId=xxxxx000mVQp"
 //."PortalId="    
     . "&username=portal user name"     
     . "&password=xxxxx" ; 

$curl = curl_init($token_url);
curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $params);


 $json_response = curl_exec($curl);

 curl_close($curl);

  $response = json_decode($json_response, true);

 //$access_token = $response['access_token'];
//$instance_url = $response['instance_url'];

 echo $json_response ;`
```

Comment: Your questions is too broad. Please provide some code and be more specific around the problem. Also it would be great starting point if you read some documentation on oAuth as well as have a look at some of the following examples - http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Digging_Deeper_into_OAuth_2.0_at_Salesforce.com

Comment: I read  many articles ,blogs etc...but it doesn't give me any solutions

Comment: Please provide some code and be more specific of the issue that you're having. Don't expect someone to answer your question by providing full solution of how to authenticate with php and oauth...

Comment: ya i know i cant expect it ...i have posted my code is there any way to refer organization Id and Portal id because I dont know php.

Answer (score 2):

http://developer.force.com/cookbook/recipe/interact-with-the-forcecom-rest-api-from-php
http://blogs.developerforce.com/developer-relations/2013/02/oauth-for-portal-users.html

These two blogs are the best resources for you.Combining both i think you will be able to get to the solution

Comment: I have referred  those blogs but it cant solve my issue

Comment: Till where have you reached ?Where you able to get the site login screen ?

Comment: where you able to get access token back from sfdc?

Comment: No i dint get access token ...If i specify orgid and portal id it is throwing error like invalid user credentials..

Comment: Actually I tried with soap i am getting output ,where soap uses wsdl files to refer orgid and portal id

Comment: If you read the first post from Patt it uses REST and not SOAP and second post clarifies on how we need a force.com site and portal association and it speaks about parameters we need .

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/10244/discussion-between-manoj-chandran-and-mohith-kumar)